# Remove Bootstrap panel class when at certain screen size

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a section that has a Bootstrap accordion feature. There are 3 accordions that appear under the 3 product categories. Once the screen size is 767px wide, the 3 product categories are stacked, one on top of the other. At this point,I want each accordion to appear directly under its corresponding category.

I have something that is close to working. Here is how the HTML looks:

```
<div class="container panel panel-default">
        <div class="intro"></div>
        <div class="row people prods">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item aos-init aos-animate" id="productOneButton" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="600">
                <div class="box">
                    <img class="img-circle no-circle" src="[img path].jpg"
                         data-bs-hover-animate="pulse">

                    <h3 class="name2">Product 1</h3>

                    <p class="description2">Product 1 description</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#product-one" type="button">More Information
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item aos-init aos-animate" id="productTwoButton" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="750">
                <div class="box">
                    <img class="img-circle no-circle" src="[img path].jpg"
                         data-bs-hover-animate="pulse">

                    <h3 class="name2">Product Two</h3>

                    <p class="description2">Product 2 description</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-parent="#accordion" id="productTwoButton" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#product-two" type="button">More Information
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item aos-init aos-animate" id="productThreeButton" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="900">
                <div class="box">
                    <img class="img-circle no-circle" src="[img path].jpg"
                         data-bs-hover-animate="pulse">

                    <h3 class="name2">Product Three</h3>

                    <p class="description2">Product three description</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#product-three" type="button">More Information
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="products-accordion panel-collapse collapse" id="product-one">
            <div class="arrow-up"></div>
            <div class="accordion-container">
                <p>Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur nec mollis magna. Donec viverra, felis id scelerisque accumsan,
                    dui velit scelerisque tellus, in blandit nisl ante eu dui. Aliquam sodales libero ac lectus
                    vehicula mollis. Suspendisse viverra diam arcu, non placerat risus pretium sit amet. Vivamus
                    varius, lorem vitae fermentum dignissim, sapien eros tincidunt nisi, quis rhoncus libero tellus
                    vulputate tellus. Nulla non ex id sapien ultricies placerat. Sed consequat felis elementum
                    ullamcorper ultricies.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="products-accordion panel-collapse collapse" id="product-two">
            <div class="arrow-up"></div>
            <div class="accordion-container">
                <p>Praesent tempor augue lorem, vel elementum ante ornare eget. Donec pharetra, ex ultrices pellentesque
                    imperdiet, dui risus pharetra elit, pulvinar feugiat felis ligula at augue. Sed convallis eget justo
                    sed tincidunt. Morbi lobortis metus quis massa consectetur scelerisque. Duis volutpat suscipit
                    tellus, tincidunt elementum est volutpat nec. Pellentesque eleifend erat lorem, et efficitur neque
                    convallis eu. Aenean aliquam nisi ut metus aliquam faucibus. Mauris at congue ex. Morbi dapibus
                    velit
                    non est laoreet egestas. Nulla turpis neque, interdum in tincidunt vitae, gravida id elit. Nunc
                    felis
                    risus, faucibus ut ipsum eget, dictum placerat ligula. Mauris ultricies diam ut congue
                    scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="products-accordion panel-collapse collapse" id="product-three">
            <div class="arrow-up"></div>
            <div class="accordion-container">
                <p>Phasellus laoreet porttitor augue at placerat. Morbi ac turpis leo. Proin elementum risus augue, sit
                    amet luctus ante porta vel. Vestibulum pharetra felis condimentum, dignissim metus at, fermentum
                    justo.
                    Suspendisse eget mi placerat, mollis nunc id, euismod tortor. Integer quis lacus nec lacus maximus
                    venenatis. Integer sed scelerisque lacus. Nunc bibendum sodales ligula, eu dignissim dolor. Fusce
                    ullamcorper velit quis ex porta blandit. In placerat, lorem eget imperdiet pulvinar, nisi arcu
                    bibendum
                    ipsum, ac porta quam felis sed erat. Vivamus est nulla, vestibulum a sem sed, blandit congue purus.
                    Praesent aliquam, felis et egestas ornare, tortor eros lobortis leo, laoreet volutpat dui nisl a
                    lectus.
                    Praesent ullamcorper eget enim eu tristique. Cras purus dolor, aliquet at gravida id, placerat ac
                    lectus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $(window).width() + 16;

        var product1Container = $('#product-one');
        var product2Container = $('#product-two');
        var product3Container = $('#product-three');

        var productOneButton = $('#productOneButton');
        var productTwoButton = $('#productTwoButton');
        var productThreeButton = $('#productThreeButton');

        var ProductsSection = $('.prods');

        if (windowsize <= 767) {
            productOneButton.append(product1Container);
            productTwoButton.append(product2Container);
            productThreeButton.append(product3Container);

            product1Container.removeClass('in');
            product2Container.removeClass('in');
            product3Container.removeClass('in');
        }
        else{
            product1Container.insertAfter(ProductsSection);
            product2Container.insertAfter(ProductsSection);
            product3Container.insertAfter(ProductsSection);

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

The problem is that the 'in' class is being removed every single time the screen is resized to a width smaller than 767px. I only want the remove the 'in' class when I get to 767px. I tried using a media query to set `display: none` for each accordion div at 767px, but that ruins the slide up animation effect of the accordion, so it just appears or disappears (not very appealing to look at).

Is there a way I can modify my jQuery to remove the 'in' class ONLY at the screen size of 767px without ruining the animation effect of the accordion?

Comment: Why do you expect that your users will be resizing the screen enough that it's an issue? Maybe a fiddle demo would help me see the problem. It seems like you're trying to resolve UI issues that either don't or shouldn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a temporary variable to track that if the removal has been done already.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var temp = 0;
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $(window).width() + 16;

        var product1Container = $('#product-one');
        var product2Container = $('#product-two');
        var product3Container = $('#product-three');

        var productOneButton = $('#productOneButton');
        var productTwoButton = $('#productTwoButton');
        var productThreeButton = $('#productThreeButton');

        var ProductsSection = $('.prods');

        if (windowsize <= 767 && temp == 0) {
            productOneButton.append(product1Container);
            productTwoButton.append(product2Container);
            productThreeButton.append(product3Container);

            product1Container.removeClass('in');
            product2Container.removeClass('in');
            product3Container.removeClass('in');
            temp ++;
        }
        else{
            product1Container.insertAfter(ProductsSection);
            product2Container.insertAfter(ProductsSection);
            product3Container.insertAfter(ProductsSection);
            temp = 0;
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle?

Comment: I worked on it with someone over the weekend and found a solution. I'll try and post it here today or tomorrow.